# Copying strings over floats in 'Do While' loop

Tags: string, vba, excel, loops

I'm attempting to create a macro that copies a string over a float/integer in the next few cells until it hits another string.  I've found some code that I thought would work and would like help modifying it (or if I should go in a different direction, tell me):

```
Sub ReplaceNumberswithText()
' Performs Do loop, testing at top of loop.
' Loops until empty cell is reached.
' Note that you can also use a Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) loop.



  ' Test contents of active cell; if active cell is empty, exit loop.
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

  If ActiveCell.Text Then Text.Copy
  End If
     ' Copies cell contents.


     ' Step down 1 row to the next cell.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

     Selection.Paste

    Else: If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     End If


    ' Return to top of loop.
    Loop
End Sub
```

I need to copy each string over the following floats/integers, until the next string. Then repeat until the end of the column (column A).

http://www.flickr.com/photos/hillsindustries/12198631954/

Comment: That would be great.  I am definitely open to suggestions... The sheet is about 11,000 rows, so copy-paste will take a couple of days' hard labor I'd say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select range, Home > Editing > Find & Select, Go To Special…, Constants, Numbers (only), OK, <kbd>Del</kbd>, `=`,Up, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: That will let me look at our inventory and margin in couple of different ways.  Nice tip on being able to slice and dice this info.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Perfect solution.  If I had more rep, I would vote up!

Comment: + 1 For Non VBA Solution. @user3246871: `If I had more rep, I would vote up!` I did it for you :)

Comment: No please don't do that :)

Comment: Thank you again for this. Our inventory system turns out the same type of formatting on many crucial reports.  I have used this solution multiple times with a lot of personal time being saved.  Thanks.